# Manually leave room after socket.disconnect()

Tags: socket.io

I've seen this on the socketio wiki.

> Note that it is not necessary to call socket.leave() during the
>   disconnect event. This will happen automatically. Empty rooms will be
>   automatically pruned so there is no need to manually remove them.

But after some tests, it is not working. After disconnecting (server-side or client-side), the socket is not removed from his room. So my question is, the previous text is still relevant or not ? Because either i have a problem in my code or the wiki is not updated.

I've tried to check inside the socketio code to check this out but i couldn't track the code to see what happens.

If the text is still relevant, when is the room leaved, after or before the code that we put inside the on('disconnected') event ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always delete the entry under `socket.namespace.manager.rooms` that contains your socket.

```
socket.join(socket.id);
console.log(socket.namespace.manager.rooms['/'+socket.id]);
socket.namespace.manager.rooms["/"+socket.id].splice(socket.namespace.manager.rooms["/"+socket.id].indexOf(socket.id),1);
console.log(socket.namespace.manager.rooms['/'+socket.id]);
```

This returns

```
[ '36_IcxqkWgBgLfC6p3Yj' ]
[]
```

Comment: I agree, that's what i do but is it normal that the room is not leave automatically after disconnect ?

Comment: How are you checking whether or not a socket is in a room?

Comment: this.io.of(mynamespace).clients(myroom).length (if 1 socket is still connected, if 0 it has been removed / is that wrong ?)

Comment: Try `io.sockets.clients('room')` instead, or `socket.namespace.manager.rooms['/'+socket.id].length`